# Load data into ExtJS app at loadtime

Tags: node.js, security, extjs, passport.js

I have a database of users and their security credentials. I'm using passport (node authentication middleware) to authenticate users before serving my main ExtJS `app.js`. Is there a way to configure my `app.js` with the user's security credentials as I'm serving `app.js`? I.e, if Bob is authenticated with security clearance 4, how can I configure my Ext JS app to reflect this security level? I'm quite unfamiliar with web programming..(but learning!)

Comment: Are you using any server side language like ASP.NET?

Comment: @drew630 I'm running node.js